# How to auto format python kwargs to newlines in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, formatting, autoformatting, autoformat

In VS Code, Python: How can keyword arguments:

```py
    number = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, unique=True, verbose_name=_('Contract number'))
```

be automatically formatted into separate lines:

```py
    number = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        unique=True,
        verbose_name=_('Contract number')
    )
```

I wasn't able to find such configuration option, is there a way to archive/force the above formatting style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`black`](https://github.com/psf/black) as your formatter and then add a comma `,` after the last argument in your function definition and `black` will span them to new lines:

```py
number = models.CharField(
    max_length=10,
    unique=True,
    verbose_name=_('Contract number'),  # note the comma here
)
```